# How to make an array formula for vlookup nested iferror in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this formula working in excel.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A:A,'JOD ID - DONE'!B:C,2,FALSE),IFERROR(VLOOKUP('JOD ID - CURRENT'!A:A,'JOD ID - DONE'!E:F,2,FALSE),IFERROR(VLOOKUP('JOD ID - CURRENT'!A:A,'JOD ID - DONE'!H:I,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP('JOD ID - CURRENT'!A:A,'JOD ID - DONE'!K:L,2,FALSE))))
```

I want to have a return value that matches from sheet2 in sheet1, the return value is the status of the Job ID that contains status "done", "re-do" and "pending" in sheet2. Sheet2 contain 4 table status. How can the formula above be an array formula?

Because actual data, I have 2000 Job ID in sheet1 need to compare from 20-30 table from sheet2.
is this possible, somehow?

*Below is sample worksheet*

[image: sheet1]

[image: sheet2]

Comment: Have your tried stepping through your formula to see where its blowing up on you?

Comment: If you are using an array formula, you do not want to use full column references such as A:A as it will cause the formula to look in all the unused cells and do a calculation there.  If you have 2000 rows or data, you want to limit your data to what you need to work with, or potentially will few more rows if you know some rows may be added in the future.  So maybe 2200 rows in your case or something similar.

Comment: Are the numbers that are throwing the #NA error actually in your look up tables?

Comment: Will the job Id only appear once in all the tables?

Comment: Would it be acceptable to use a helping column?

Comment: @ScottCraner  yes, the job id is unique in all table reference

Answer (score 1):

I did a little bit of testing with some dummy data to generate a #NA error.  For me I had this error when the number was not found when it did not appeared in any of the tables.  I dealt with this case by wrapping your formula in another IFERROR to give a not found situation.  Place the following formula in B1 and copy down as needed.

```
=IFERROR(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,'JOD ID - DONE'!B:C,2,FALSE),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,'JOD ID - DONE'!E:F,2,FALSE),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,'JOD ID - DONE'!H:I,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP(A2,'JOD ID - DONE'!K:L,2,FALSE)))),"NOT FOUND")
```

Lookup Results

[image: Current]

Reference Data

[image: Look up data]

When encountering an error, especially with nested and long formulas, try reducing your formula to a very small amount of data to make sure its working with the small amount before expanding it.  In this case I would have done the look up with either just the first table or just a single nest of the second table.  When that is working I would expend out the nesting to suit my needs or increase the data size depending on the situation.

***UPDATE FOR MULTIPLE TABLES***

ASSUMING the job ID is unique in the entire sheet containing your look up tables you could do something like the following, but it is important to restrict the range of the data inside the aggregate function to roughly close the maximum number of rows and columns used by all your tables.  The key is to avoid excess calculations on blank cells

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('JOD ID - DONE'!$1:$1048576,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW('JOD ID - DONE'!$B$2:$L$4)/('JOD ID - DONE'!$B$2:$L$4=A2),1),AGGREGATE(14,6,COLUMN('JOD ID - DONE'!$B$2:$L$4)/('JOD ID - DONE'!$B$2:$L$4=A2),1)+1),"NOT FOUND")
```

In your case you will want to edit $B2:$L$4 to match your data.

If your Job ID is not unique to all tables then this method may not give the results you expect.

Comment: The OP is not looking for why they get the error, but how to expand it to 20 to 30 tables without having to do 20-30 IFERRORs

Comment: @ScottCraner  missed that one completely!  BTW Merry Christmas and all the best to you and the Craner clan in 2020

Comment: however the intent of my question is like what @FowardEd stated